# Getting a Syntax Error While doing a ajax post form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two div containers. One div has a form and the other has a lot of sensitive content that I would like to hide. They are both built with bootstrap.

The idea is that the first form requires a person to enter a password and then this should trigger a ajax post call to the backend to check if the password is correct and if it is, the second container will be revealed.

in my routes.rb

```
post 'users/trial_signup_validation', to: 'users#trial_signup_validation'
```

in my users_controller.rb

```
  def trial_signup_validation
    @password = params['password']
    if @password == 'sales'
      render :json => { "success" : "true" }
    else 
      render :json => { "success" : "false" }
  end
```

The method takes the object from the ajax post and check it, then return a json true or false back to the view.

Here is the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#protectivepanel").submit(function(event) {

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/users/trial_signup_validation", 
        data: $("#protectivepanel").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          return data.success 
        } 
    }); 
  event.preventDefault()
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#the_submit_button").click(function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault();
        if (data.success){
          $("#protectivepanel").hide() 
          $("#salespanel > div").removeClass("hide")
        }
        else {
          $("#protectivepanel").show()
        }   
    });
  });
</script>
```

my first form looks like this

```
<div class="container" id="protectivepanel">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="representativepassword">Representative's Password</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="representativepassword" placeholder=" Enter Password">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="the_submit_button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

also when I run `rails s`, I am getting a syntax error pointing to another method in the same controller which makes no sense to me.

```
SyntaxError at /users/trial_signup
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
```

this method works perfectly before I started working on the jquery form posting.

Comment: Is your javascript comment prefixed with a `#`? That would be a syntax error.

Comment: oh no I just added that on stackoverflow to comment something, my js is bad. that is the ruby way....

Comment: Right, I didn't see the syntax error at the bottom immediately, so I wasn't sure where it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `trial_signup_validation` as below:

```
 def trial_signup_validation
    @password = params['password']
    if @password == 'sales'
      render :json => { "success" => "true" }  ## Use hash rocket instead of :
    else 
      render :json => { "success" => "false" }  ## Use hash rocket instead of :
  end
```

NOTE:

`"success" and "true"` are both `Strings` so you will have to use `hash rocket(=>)` to denote hash syntax, you cannot use `:` because there is no symbol.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't this method exactly the same as mine?

Comment: @Jngai1297 Read Note in my answer

Comment: great! that fixed my syntax error but my form isn't entirely working? now that when I type in 'sales' to the input box, the second container doesn't show.

Comment: My answer resolves your current syntax error specifically to this question. We cannot chain Questions in Comments and neither extend the solved question. Accept this answer and post a new question related to your new issue. That is as per SO standard.

Comment: Glad to help.:) If you post another question. You can ping me here or join me in chat for discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: would you like to answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765227/jquery-ajax-post-return-data-uncaught-referenceerror-data-is-not-defined