# Jquery ajax post return data , Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a script that grabs the input text field from a div container called the protectivepanel. 
I am doing an ajax post call for this text field to be checked in the backend.
If a person enters the correct password then we unhide another div container panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#protectivepanel").submit(function(event) {

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/users/trial_signup_validation",
        data: $("#protectivepanel").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          console.log('data request succeeded'); 
          return data
        } 
    }); 
  event.preventDefault()
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#the_submit_button").click(function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('event.preventDefault');
        if (data.success){
          console.log('data'); 
          $("#protectivepanel").hide() 
          $("#salespanel > div").removeClass("hide")
        }
        else {
          $("#protectivepanel").show()
        }   
    });
  });
</script>
```

here is the method that is checking with

```
  def trial_signup_validation
    @password = params['password']
    if @password == 'sales'
      render :json => { "success" => "true" }
    else 
      render :json => { "success" => "false" }
    end
  end
```

Now I want the it to returned the json data and if its a success then we unhide the panel in the script.

my chrome console has this when I enter 'sales' in my text box and hit submit

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Here is my form if its needed

```
<div class="container" id="protectivepanel">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="representativepassword">Representative's Password</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="representativepassword" placeholder=" Enter Password">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="the_submit_button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I don't understand if I am doing the callback correctly. My server log isn't showing the ajax post call. How do I know that I am getting the correct returned data ?

Comment: You can't do `return data` from an asynchronous function. You need to use a callback, or the promise interface.

Answer (score 1):

The `e.preventDefault` in `#the_submit_button`'s click event prevents the submission of the form which actually makes the ajax call.  Since the `submit` event is bound outside of `document.ready`, it is possible that nothing is bound either.

Finally, you cannot return from the ajax callback.  Anything that relies on the result of the callback has to be done within the scope of the callback.  Fix these three things:

1. Do not `preventDefault` for the submit button click event
2. Make sure that `#protectivepanel` exists when you bind to it.
3. Move the `hide`/`removeClass` functionality into your `success` callback function.  You may also want to provide an `error` callback.

Comment: I think I have figured it out to not use submit a form and wrap everything in a click event instead.

Comment: @Jngai1297 be careful about that because there may be other ways to submit the form